# How can I use VisualRecognition classifiers in Swift

Tags: ibm-watson

Related to : https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk#visual-recognition, I inserted the classifierIDs parameter:

```
import VisualRecognitionV3
let apiKey = "your-apikey-here"
let version = "YYYY-MM-DD" // use today's date for the most recent version
let visualRecognition = VisualRecognition(apiKey: apiKey, version: version)
let url = "your-image-url"
let failure = { (error: NSError) in print(error) }
visualRecognition.classify(url, classifierIDs: "x", failure: failure) { classifiedImages in
    print(classifiedImages)
}
```

This results in an error:

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'classify(_:owner:classifierIDs:showLowConfidence:outputLanguage:failure:success)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the `ambiguous reference` error usually results from a type mismatch. In this case, there are two `classify` functions in the SDK, one where the first argument is a `String` and another where the first argument is a `NSURL`. The `ambiguous reference` error occurs because the compiler cannot use type inference to disambiguate the two `classify` functions and determine which you intend to execute.

I believe the particular issue here relates to the `classifierIDs` parameter. According to the [documentation](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/ios-sdk/services/VisualRecognitionV3/Classes/VisualRecognition.html#/s:FC19VisualRecognitionV317VisualRecognition8classifyFTSS6ownersGSqGSaSS__13classifierIDsGSqGSaSS__17showLowConfidenceGSqSb_14outputLanguageGSqSS_7failureGSqFCSo7NSErrorT__7successFVS_16ClassifiedImagesT__T_), the type of `classifierIDs` is `[String]?`, which does not match the type of `"x"`. Try `["x"]` instead.

That is, try:

```
visualRecognition.classify(url, classifierIDs: ["x"], failure: failure) { classifiedImages in
    print(classifiedImages)
}
```